# Is there a way to create an array of an element that contains a specific CSS style?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture the elements that do not contain a display type of none.

```
let pfCard = document.getElementsByClassName("PortfolioCard").style.display = 'block';
```

This doesn't seem to be working as I believe it is attempting to modify the style type instead of retrieve it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by getting all your elements by class name and then using `filter` on that list.

```js
 const blockElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("PortfolioCard")].filter(x => x.style.display == "block");
 console.log(blockElements.length);
```

```html
<div class="PortfolioCard" style="display:block">block</div>
<div class="PortfolioCard">not block</div>
<div class="PortfolioCard" style="display:block">block</div>
```

Comment: I think this would have worked but I didn't realize bootstrap is setting the display type so it is returning the entire array as if there was no filter. Going to have to find a work around for that but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to `querySelectorAll(".PortfolioCard")` to get an array of them, then `.filter()` the array looking for `style.display != 'none'`.

A nicer solution would be if you separate your `display: none` property into a small utility class like: `.hide-portfolio { display: none; }`, and hide them that way. Then you can search for them with `querySelectorAll(".PortfolioCard:not(.hide-portfolio)");`

Comment: querySelectorAll does not return an array with filter method

Comment: Well spotted, @charlietfl ! I hadn't realised that before. Well, at least it looks like most browsers can `.forEach` over a NodeList.

Comment: That is in the NodeLIst prototype and acts the same as array version but a NodeList is not an array  it is array-like

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```js
console.log([...document.getElementsByClassName("PortfolioCard")].filter(item=> window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('display') != "block"))
```

```html
<div class='PortfolioCard' style='display:block'></div>
<div class="PortfolioCard" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="PortfolioCard" style='display:none'></div>
```

Or use`array.forEach`:

```js
let arr= [];
[...document.getElementsByClassName("PortfolioCard")].forEach(item=>{
if(window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('display') != "block") 
arr.push(item)
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class='PortfolioCard' style='display:block'></div>
<div class="PortfolioCard" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="PortfolioCard" style='display:none'></div>
```